# C#: Bind data controls with custom connection string at design time?

Tags: .net, encryption, connection-string

My application has a database property page which includes settings for server, database, user id, password. I have a custom EncryptedSettings class (derived from ApplicationSettingsBase) which encrypts and decrypts under the user's account using DPAPI.

I also have a class which builds the connection string on the fly - it looks something similar to AppSettings.ConnectionString (where ConnectionString is a property). AppSettings performs the decryption by calling into EncryptedSettings and returns the connection string.

Is it possible to instruct data controls (such as DataGridView) to use AppSettings.ConnectionString at design time for binding? I don't want plain text secrets in app.config, and I don't want to force admins to use command line tools to protect secrets (or force admins to edit connection strings in app.settings).

Jeff

Comment: What do you mean by "instruct"? You wouldn't tell a datagridview to use a connection string, but rather fill the datagridview with a dataset, or use a datareader.

Comment: Good point broke - I was not clear. I want the design time binding with my custom connection string provider.

Comment: You can't get a custom connection string like you want at design time, but you can use the objectdatasource to connect to your Data Access Layer Class, which will get your design time support you want.  Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx

Comment: Also, check out this video on asp.net: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-03&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro